# Keep custom GET parameters over POST request in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, get

I need to keep my custom get parameter over ANY form submit in WordPress. For instance, I have post edit like /wp-admin/post.php?post=493&action=edit&foo=bar
Then I click update and gone, there's no foo in url.

I even added ?foo=bar to action='post.php' and still nothing. I also added foo to public query_vars . I searched a lot and found nothing related to this problem. Is there a way to do what I want? I can use javascript/jquery to manipulate the forms.

Comment: action='post.php' is form submit page name.???

Comment: Yes, but I meant that I changed <form action='post.php' ... to <form action='post.php?foo=bar'...

Comment: I finally solved this problem by using sessions and injecting get parameter like action='post.php?foo=bar' . It doesn't keep foo=bar in url, but it stores the information I need.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please mark it as resolved or answered.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've solved the issue using `$_SESSION` however for anyone else that needs this sort of functionality and can't use the session for any reason, this is also an option:

```
<form action="post.php?<?= http_build_query($_GET); ?>">
```

It looks a bit ugly, but it'll repeat any _GET parameters into the action.

To test, I made this slightly awful way of tacking everything together:

```
<form method="post" action="?<?= http_build_query($_GET);?>&<?= http_build_query($_POST);?>">
    <label> Test<input name="<?= time() ?>"></label>
</form>
```

Note: You have to submit a few times before it starts appearing in the url as first submission is in `POST`, which is then added to the `GET` in the second post. (It'll always look like it's one behind, but if you look at the html it'll be right).

**Final note:** All parameters sent via [get, post and/or cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), are available in `$_REQUEST`.